# Oracle Trigger after restricted session and db startup

Tags: database, oracle, triggers, eventtrigger

I have an Oracle db 11 that contains 3 instances. I need that event 31156 will be trace forever,
so I run this alter statment on each instance:

```
alter system set events '31156 trace name context forever, level 0x400';
```

The problem is that this parameter resets every time the db is restarted or getting into restricted mode and out of restricted mode.

I want to create 2 db triggers that will run this command, one after start up and the second after disabling restricted mode.

I created the start up trigger like that:

```
create trigger on_startup_trig after startup on database begin
  alter system set events '31156 trace name context forever, level 0x400';
end;
```

so my first question is - will this trigger run on each of my instances when the db will be started or only once?
my second question is - is there a way to create a simmilar trigger for after disabling restricted session?
I disable restricted session like that:

```
alter system disable restricted session;
```

Comment: I don't know what you are  referring to as an "instance" vs "db" but the trigger needs to exist in each database.

Comment: I mean that the db application is running on 3 different servers and each server is an instance. They are all synchronized and contain the same data, and application connect to a cluster that navigate them to the available instance (like load balancer in web servers)

Comment: You mean RAC with three nodes?